# Extracting GPS coordinates(Latitude,Longitude) from pictures

Tags: python, computer-vision, metadata, openstreetmap, image-recognition

I am working on the images dataset with 1000,s of pictures. I am trying to find the geo-locations of these images and inside objects also. While searching the internet, I have found some useful suggestions [here](https://exposingtheinvisible.org/resources/image-digging) but they are not much useful.

- Is it possible to get `GPS coordinates` from `captured images`?
- Additionally, Is there a way to detect GPS coordinates of `objects` as shown in the red block in below picture?

[image]

Comment: Usually the metadata will have GPS coords for the image provided that the camera was allowed to embed this information.  However, looking at this purely from an image itself is practically impossible.  What is your rationale behind just using image data for extracting GPS coordinates?

Comment: Computers don't have depth perception or any means to understand the scale on the images. I could look at it and say that the transformer (or whatever it is in red box) is about 1.4-1.5 m in height, but in order for computer to do the same, you'd need to create a deep learning model and train it extensively. It's possible but requires a lot of effort.

Comment: The extracted images are captured manually from GoogleMaps street view instead of mobile cameras, so there is no metadata of GPS coordinates. The rationale is to find the location of assets installed in public places.

Comment: This is unfortunately not possible because there can be places of interest that look very similar to each other but could have completely different GPS coordinates.  I personally do not think it's possible to train even a deep learning model to infer the GPS coordinates given the image.  You would have to capture the same locations in a variety of different scenarios, illuminations and object decompositions.  Even more so, the exact localization of objects inside the image will have accuracy problems because the error tolerance depending on the GPS sensor can vary widely.

Comment: @pavel. Yes, I am thinking the same to train a deep learning model, especially with CNN. But it needs a lot of data for training. There is no such data in public. Using the available images I want to generate the dataset first then later implement the trained model to new locations (test images). the imput of the model is images and output is GPS coordinates( Lat,Lon)

Comment: @CaseMsee, what I meant was a deep learning model for depth/object size identification. I agree with rayryeng that it would be almost impossible to make a model that will give you coordinates if your images don't come with any metadata.